# Issue in creating bot for webtalk autolike & autoshare by using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, webautomation

after launching the chrome browser i tried through many approaches to enter user name and password automatically by using class name,xpath,by id but still no auto input of user name and password at homepage .

Comment: Can you share the URL or relevant HTML?

Comment: We need to see your code, and error stack trace to guide you.

Comment: sir i have shared the code attached kindly help me ur is             https://www.webtalk.co/o/home

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please add the code to the question so we can solve it without going to an external site.  I'd recommend reading the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

yes Manish URL Is
https://www.webtalk.co/o
i am sharing you code in an while.
i am sharing code in a while sir
i have alsos shared the code as well

Comment: sir i have shared the code i have tried multiple methods finding by id,classname,xpath,fullxpath but still i am unable to get that please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
    from selenium import webdriver
import time
username = input("Enter in your username: ")
time.sleep(2)
password = input("Enter in your password: ")
time.sleep(2)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.webtalk.co/o/home")
time.sleep(10)
username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="userName"]")
time.sleep(2)
username_textbox.send_keys(username)
password_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/section/wt-default-onboarding-page/div/div/div/wt-homepage-component/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/wt-signin/div[1]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input")
time.sleep(2)
password_textbox.send_keys(password)
time.sleep(2)
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="signInSubmit"]")
time.sleep(2)
login_button.click()
```